# Save handler in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to save the data from my program using an event handler.
Here's the code I have in the controller:

```
private class SaveMenuHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Student.dat"));) {

            oos.writeObject(model);
            oos.flush();

            alertDialogBuilder("Information Dialog", "Save success", "Student Profile saved to StudentProfile.dat");

        }
        catch (IOException ioExcep){
            System.out.println("Error saving");
        }

    }
}
```

This code just gives me "Error Saving" in the Console

Any help is appreciated.

Here's the errors:

```
Error saving
java.lang.Exception
    at controller.ProfileController$SaveMenuHandler.handle(ProfileController.java:194)
    at controller.ProfileController$SaveMenuHandler.handle(ProfileController.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you be a little more specific on what I'm ignoring please?

Comment: Your current code is certainly not throwing this exception. `Exception` is not a subclass of `IOException` which means you're not printing the stack trace for `ioExcep`, but probably for some exception you only created for the sake of having a stacktrace to print to the console...

Comment: What's ProfileController line 194 and line 1?

Comment: If you are using an IDE like Netbeans, you are probably actually running a different program than you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code in your catch block so you can see the exact error message. Your code should look like this. Run your program again and post the error message it will generate:

```
private class SaveMenuHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Student.dat"));) {

            oos.writeObject(model);
            oos.flush();

            alertDialogBuilder("Information Dialog", "Save success", "Student Profile saved to StudentProfile.dat");

        }
        catch (IOException ioExcep){
            System.out.println("Error saving");
            //Print the complete error message
            ioExcep.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message please? That will help me to see what's wrong. And please remember: An error message is never just an error. It's your key to fix problems in your software.

Comment: I've edited the original post with the errors. I looked through them myself but can't understand what is wrong.

Comment: @fabian You are right. I didn't saw that his Exception is named "ioException'. The last line of code should be ioExcep.printStackTrace();

Comment: @fabian & Max. Sorry guys, forgot to update you. Implemented serializable in my model classes and it worked!